# How to make the css hover/focus pseudo class work properly

Tags: css

I created a white menu, which when the mouse is over should turn red, unfortunately it doesn't work. Through the browser console it seems to work only if I delete:

```css
color: white;
```

Here is the complete code:

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .lagom-layout-condensed #main-menu .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    color: white;
  } 
  .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a:focus, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a:focus, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a:hover, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: try to add `!important` to be like this `color: red !important;`

Comment: I suggest you include an li.nav-item & a.nav-link class to your navigation to cleanup it a little bit. Than you can just do .nav-link {} in both places to override it clean.

Comment: As a general rule, **never** use id selectors in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS specificity problem. Your first rule is more specific than your second rule, because the first rule contains an ID (`#main-menu`). Because of this `color:white` will be considered more important than `color:red`, so the latter is never applied.

There are two solutions:

1. Simplify your CSS rules to solve the specificity issue;
2. Change `color:red` to `color:red !important` to force it to override the more specific rule.

Comment: Great stuff. It this resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a {
     padding-left: 13px;
     padding-right: 13px;
     color: white;
   } 
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a:focus, 
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a:focus,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li.open>a:hover,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
   .navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
     color: red;
   }
}
```

Remove these selectors ".lagom-layout-condensed #main-menu"

Adding “!important”is not recommended